# SQL Server: group by, coalesce and select one of coalesce'd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Regions`:

```
city        district1   district2   district3   district4
---------------------------------------------------------
Michigan    2           NULL        NULL        2
Michigan    2           20          NULL        20
Michigan    2           NULL        3           3
Ontario     3           NULL        NULL        3
Quebec      4           1           NULL        1
Quebec      4           NULL        NULL        4
Edmonton    NULL        7           NULL        7
Edmonton    NULL        NULL        11          11
```

`district4` is `(coalesce(district3, district2, district1))`

And I'd like to get a distinct grouped by City also with district1

```
city        district1   district_final
--------------------------------------    
Michigan    2           3
Ontario     3           3
Quebec      4           1
Edmonton    NULL        11
```

`district_final` is not max; it's coalesce of group

Comment: So district_final is the max() of district4?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Your title basically describes what you need. Just implement it.

Comment: What if Michigan have non null values for all 3 rows in `district3` column? then which one should choose as `district_final` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze there's no situation like described;
if district1 exists then (district2 is null and district3 is null) or district2 is not null or district3 is not null
if district1 doesn't exists then district2 is not null or district3 is not null

district4 is coalesce of 3,2,1 (in this order)
district_final should be also coalesce of 3,2,1 but with grouping by district1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct r1.city, r1.district1,  coalesce(r3.district3, r2.district2, r1.district1) district_final
from Regions r1
left outer join Regions r2 on r1.city = r2.city and r2.district2 is not null
left outer join Regions r3 on r1.city = r3.city and r3.district3 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should solve the purpose i guess:

```
 SELECT CITY,dct1 as district1,MAX(DCT) as district_final FROM
(
SELECT CITY, district1 as dct1, district1 AS DCT FROM [TABLE] 
UNION
SELECT CITY, district1 as dct1, district2 AS DCT FROM [TABLE] 
UNION
SELECT CITY, district1 as dct1, district3 AS DCT FROM [TABLE] 
) tempTable
group by CITY,dct1;
```